# Has anyone went from PHP templating to XSLT templating and not regretted it?

Tags: php, xslt, templating

There is a certain framework I'm using in which the main developers are considering drastically changing from native PHP based templating to XSLT templating.

I'm worried that this won't be feasible because on our sites we usually have very complex templating logic.

For something as simple as this:

```
    if ( $something ) { ?>
        <p><?php if ( $another ) { ?>Lorem Ipsum<?php } else { ?>Dolor amet<?php } ?>.</p>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p><?php if ( $another ) { ?>Lorem Ipsum<?php } else { ?>Dolor amet<?php } ?>.</p>
    <?php } ?>
```

The equivalent XSLT would be:

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="blah">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="another">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <p>Dolor amet.</p>
                </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:when test="another">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <p>Dolor amet.</p>
                </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

With such a simple code snippet, it scares me when I think of advanced scenarios.

I'm wondering if anyone has undergone through a similar templating conversion and if so, how did you cope with it? Did you go back?

Comment: Not understanding XSLT is no reason to worry that a team has chosen to use it. A reasonable action item is to expand one's horizons. A good way to stop being scared is to start learning -- by reading and practicing. There are good learning resources, including many questions and answers in SO's "xslt" tag.

Comment: That's not a problem for me, I just worry that this will cause production levels to slow down for the majority of my team (interface development, which will be dealing with XSLT and template logic from now on, instead of backend developers), and we run on tight deadlines as it is already.

Comment: In my experience processing XML with XSLT is orders of magnitude faster than with traditional imperative languages. The quality is much higher with orders of magnitude fewer bugs. You could even be able to do the same work with less developers.

Answer (score 6):

In XSLT 1.0 your proposed code can be simplified to:

```
<p>
   <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="blah">
                <xsl:when test="another">Lorem Ipsum.</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>Dolor amet.</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:when test="another">Lorem Ipsum.</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>Dolor amet.</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</p>
```

In XSLT 2.0 it can be further simplified to:

```
<p>
  <xsl:value-of select="if (test=blah) 
                        then if (test=another) then 'Lorem ipsum' else 'Dolor amet'
                        then if (test=another) then 'Lorem ipsum' else 'Dolor amet'"/>
</p>
```

Which strikes me as a lot nicer than your PHP original.

For the more general question, XSLT does have a steep learning curve. Those who stick with it and master the concepts are generally very happy with the language. But quite a few people get cold feet and give up before getting to that point, because it is so different from anything they have encountered before.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, eventually, I always go back to plain `.phtml` files - not that this is the right thing or the ideal thing, but what solved the problems at the time.

XSLT never got things right for me, even for simpler logic templates.

If there is any template system that has made me happy, that was [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).